# Python, Assert на user_name

Tags: python

Код в консоли такой:

```
<a class="1" id="user_name" href="/editor">Gleb</a>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как написать assert на user_name (что имя user_name совпадает с ожидаемым"
Такой код не сработал (Python):

```
name = s.find(userName).__contains__("Gleb")
assert name == "Gleb", "Не совпадение имени логина!"
```

Comment: 1) `s.find(userName).__contains__("Gleb")` это ведь вернет `True`, а `True` не будет равно `"Gleb"` 2) Нет смысла напрямую вызывать магические методы, используйте оператор `in`: `"Gleb" in s.find(userName)` 3) `s.find` метод `find` это ваш метод или стандартный метод типа питона?

Comment: Скорее всего должно быть `name = s.find(userName) (перенос строки) assert name == "Gleb", "Не совпадение имени логина!"` без `__contains__`